# insert a single random string from a list, one at a time, every 2 seconds, only one note at a time should appear in tkinter listbox

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I'm using tkinter and I need to display one string from a list containing 6 strings in the gui listbox. I need each string to display on its own every 2 seconds and I need the program to start on the click of a button. Right now, my program is outputting all of the items in the list

so far, I can output the strings as one full list, however I need each item to display on its own, timed, and at random.

```
import time
import random
from select import select
from tkinter import *
from turtle import back

def practice_key_of_c():
    c = ["C","Dm","Em","F","G","Am"]
    for note in c:
        output = random.choice(c)
        list1.insert(END, output)
        time.sleep(.1)

window = Tk()

window.geometry("350x200")

list1 = Listbox(window, height = 8, width = 35)

list1.grid(row = 2, column = 0, rowspan = 6, columnspan = 2)

b1 = Button(window, text="key of c", width = 14, command=practice_key_of_c).grid(row = 2, column = 3)

window.wm_title("guitar quiz")

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that inserts one note, and then use `after` to call it every two seconds.

```
def practice_key_of_c():
    c = ["C","Dm","Em","F","G","Am"]
    list1.insert(END, random.choice(c))
    window.after(2000, practice_key_of_c)
```